# Android build error using NativeScript Sidekick: app:mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I'm building an app with NativeScript using TypeScript and Angular. This has happened twice while building the app.

In order to add resources (like images), I add them to my_app_folder\app\App_Resources\Android\src\main\res. I accidentally added a folder called "video" with a file called "sample_video.mp4" into the res folder. When I tried to run my app on my Android emulator using the cloud build, I received this error in my NativeScript Sidekick console:

```
 /mnt/storage/builds/_/b10d99b4991d936c4896cd72f0628901fa996d4c/4.2.4/saintstanreal/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/video/sample_video.mp4: Error: The file name must end with .xml
```

I realized I had placed the file in the wrong place, deleted the video and the video folder, and tried to build the app again, but now I am consistently getting the above error, even though the offending file is long gone.

This has happened to me before (with a .png file with a capital letter in the name, which android does not like) and I would love to know why. Last time I had to delete my whole project, revert to my previous commit, and rebuild the app, which is frustrating.

My app ran perfectly fine before I added that file, so I know that the problem is not being caused by my code. I tried deleting the android platform and reinstalling it, to no avail.

Any help would be amazing as I am very confused as to why the file, which is no longer in my project, would continue to cause this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a **clean build** to reset the data that was cached.

In Sidekick go to **Build** and from the menu options check **Clean Build**

> When you enable the Clean Build option, any previously cached data
>   will be ignored and the application will undergo a complete rebuild.
>   This type of build will not take advantage of certain optimizations
>   and may take longer to finish.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I appreciate your answer.

By the time I read this answer, I had already created an issue in GitHub, which resulted in a fix being deployed. Using File -> "Clean Cloud Workspace" now resolves the problem. See the issue here: https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/264#issuecomment-423534148

Comment: Just tried fixing this with "clean build" and it did work, so thanks again, Nick.

Answer (score 1):

As of the resolution of [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/264#issuecomment-423534148) in NativeScript Sidekick, using File -> Clean Cloud Workspace fixes this problem.

If I add an incorrect resource file to Android's "res" folder, try to build (and fail), remove the incorrect file, and use the "Clean Cloud Build" command, the Android cloud build will then work as intended (without having to use the "Clean Build" checkbox when building).